# What to do when overfitting does not improve using regularization and droppout?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I'm testing Conv, GRU, LSTM and simple Dense and I don't get 70 to 80%
My network converges very fast and overfits in the first seasons, could it be the data?

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

lstm_46 (LSTM)               (None, 65, 32)            6272

---

dropout_67 (Dropout)         (None, 65, 32)            0

---

bidirectional_20 (Bidirectio (None, 65, 64)            16640

---

dropout_68 (Dropout)         (None, 65, 64)            0

---

lstm_48 (LSTM)               (None, 32)                12416

---

dropout_69 (Dropout)         (None, 32)                0

---

flatten_28 (Flatten)         (None, 32)                0

---

dense_73 (Dense)             (None, 10)                330

---

activation_72 (Activation)   (None, 10)                0

---

dense_74 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 11

---

## activation_73 (Activation)   (None, 1)                 0

Total params: 35,669
Trainable params: 35,669
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing more about the data. Some of the possible solutions can be -

1. Use a shallower network
2. Get more training data
3. Make sure your training and validation set comes from the same distribution

Comment: If it is possible to send the data, I can send it. I did several analyzes, ran fuller, and correlation. I identified that the data is stationary and little seasonal